# javac: file not found error in Atom

Tags: java, path

Currently trying to run a hello world program in Java, using Atom and the script package for Atom. Upon running the script, it gives me  an error -

`javac: file not found: Test.java`

My PATH variable is set to-

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin`

I have both the user and system PATH variables set to that. My Test.java program is under directory `D:\Programming\Java` . Any help appreciated; please put it into layman's terms.

Comment: Hi Austin, Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. javac -version

If this works, then do a dir and make sure your file is there. If it is, make sure it has the main defined in it. Like the following:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you define "do a dir?" -version does work, my code is identical except without the exception

Comment: I did dir D:\Programming\Java and my file is there

Comment: dir is a DOS command. If you are on linux, you can use ls. If everything is checking out, just make sure you have the main portion that I specified. If you get an error, copy and paste it here.

Comment: I am not on Linux, I'm using Windows.